# How to query from three tables like below

Tags: mysql

I have three tables project, daily_activity, and completed_works.
Each project may have different daily activities. Each daily activity, there are several works. You can check the below tables to get the whole idea.

project Table:

```
------------------------------------
|   PROJECT_ID  |   PROJECT_NAME    |
------------------------------------
|       1       |       PROJ1       |
------------------------------------    
|       2       |       PROJ2       |
------------------------------------
```

daily_activity Table:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   DA_ID   |   PROJECT_ID      |       DA_DATE     |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   1       |       1           |       20/12/2018  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   2       |       1           |       21/12/2018  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
|   3       |       2           |       23/12/2018  |
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

completed_works table:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ID  |       DA_ID       |       work_code       |       work_desc       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |       1           |           w001        |       work desc. 1    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |       2           |           w002        |       work desc. 2    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |       2           |           w003        |       work desc. 3    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   4   |       1           |           w004        |       work desc. 4    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
|   5   |       3           |           w005        |       work desc. 5    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get the completed works record based on project Id. First search for da_id based on project id, then fetch the record from completed works based on da_id and the main thing is I want to get da_date for example in below table you can see work_code = w001 is under DA_ID = 1 which has been completed DA_DATE = 20/12/2018.

Desired Result

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   ID  |   work_code       |       work_desc       |       DA_DATE         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |       w001        |       work desc. 1    |       20/12/2018      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |       w002        |       work desc. 2    |       21/12/2018      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |       w003        |       work desc. 3    |       21/12/2018      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   4   |       w004        |       work desc. 4    |       20/12/2018      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried but I can't understand how to get the da_date. Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM completed_works
WHERE DA_ID IN (SELECT D.ID FROM daily_activity as d WHERE PROJECT_ID = 1)
```

In this query I can get DA_IDs which are under PROJECT_ID is 1 by using IN clause. But dont have any idea how to get ithe DA_DATE.

Comment: See about JOINs

Comment: I am trying, But don't understand how to achieve this. If you have any idea so i can test it. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can show us an attempt using JOINs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally done by joining tables. I always like to do it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM completed_works, daily_activity, project,
WHERE completed_works.DA_ID = daily_activity.DA_ID AND
      aily_activity.PROJECT_ID = project.PROJECT_ID;
```

This is simple to understand. But most people would actually use the JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM completed_works
JOIN daily_activity ON completed_works.DA_ID = daily_activity.DA_ID
JOIN project ON daily_activity.PROJECT_ID = project.PROJECT_ID;
```

both queries are equivalent. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

You can select the columns you need instead of using `*`. Where joins get complicated is when you add join types. The joins above are actually inner joins.

[image]

Comment: I would remove everything up to 'understand.'

Comment: Yeah, I always get critized for that, but I think it helps to understand simple inner joins in the end. It is an intermediate step for people familiar with `SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE ...` and unfamiliar with, or afraid of,  joins. It shows that there's nothing mysterious about joins. And in the end, those queries are equivalent and perform equally well (or bad).

Comment: Yes, I got the point. Strawberry suggested me to use join. To be honest I have done this after searching some JOIN logics. Thanks, KIKO Software for your answer and explanation. You may remove everything up to 'understand' suggested by Strawberry. The else part is enough for understanding purpose. Thanks, both of you.

Comment: I love this picture